# App works on simulator but not on ipod touch

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, contacts

I have developed an app, which imports contacts into Addressbook. The app works great on simulator, but when i tested on my ipod touch, it does not work correctly. It does not crash, but instead it  give the wrong result.I have no idea what's wrong with it. Here is the code i think it works on simulator but not on ipod touch.

```
CFErrorRef couldAddPersonError = NULL;
BOOL couldAddPerson = ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook,
                                                 person,
                                                 &couldAddPersonError);

CFErrorRef couldSaveAddressBookError = NULL;
BOOL couldSaveAddressBook = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook,
                                                   &couldSaveAddressBookError);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have same contacts in iPod as you have in simulator ?

Comment: Check if the operation succeeds, then check what the error message is if the call fails.

Comment: @danielbeard The operation does not succeed. Is there any way to check error message?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", couldAddPersonError);`

Comment: @danielbeard The error shows "ABAddressBookErrorDomain Code=1". I searched the internet, but found no documentation about this error.